# Why does apply method requires parens?

Tags: scala, methods

I'm pretty new to scala and tried to write the following simple class:

```
class Test {
  def m(): Unit = println("Test method")
}

object Test{
  def apply: Test = new Test
}

val t = Test(); //error
```

But if I declare `apply` as the following:

```
object Test{
    def apply(): Test = new Test
}
```

then

```
val t = Test()
```

compiles fine.

Why? I thought we need parens if the method produces some side effect. But this is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

If it didn't need the parentheses, how would the compiler be able to know if `t` is supposed to be calling the `apply` method or just be bound to the `Test` object?

I.e.

```
val t = Test
```

This is now ambiguous, because the compiler can't decide if you want to bind `t` to a new instance of `Test`, or the `Test` companion object.

Furthermore, if you want to resolve the ambiguity, you can just call the `Test.apply` method without the syntactic sugar.

---

Additionally, what you can ask yourself is, does your `Test` class, really need to be a class? Or could it also be an `object`? Usually when you aren't passing anything to the constructor, it tends to be a sign, that you could just use a singleton instead.

Comment: Additional to this, If you want to implement apply without parens you can just call it like Test.apply